# Django - How to add multiple objects one after another

Tags: django

I want to make a Quiz app, u will enter the app and u will have 2 buttons:

1. Create a Quiz
2. Solve a Quiz

When you press "Create a quiz" you will need to insert your name and press a button that takes you to add a new question in that quiz.I can only add one question, after i press submit it stops.

**The problem** is that i want to continuously add questions and stop when i added enough. Each question to have a button **Add Next Question** that automatically saves the question and goes to add the next one and the **Finnish Quiz** button that stops the proccess of adding questions.I dont know how to add the questions continuously.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView, DetailView

from quiz.forms import QuestionForm, QuizIdentifierForm
from quiz.models import Question, QuizIdentifier


# HOMEPAGE
class HomeTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "quiz/homepage.html"


# QUIZ
class QuizCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quiz/add_quiz.html'
    model = QuizIdentifier
    form_class = QuizIdentifierForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('add-question', kwargs={'quiz_id': self.object.pk})


class QuizDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'quiz/detail_quiz.html'
    model = QuizIdentifier


# QUESTION
class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quiz/add_question.html'
    model = Question
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        res = super().form_valid(form)
        self.object.quiz_id = self.kwargs['quiz_id']
        self.object.save()
        return res


def get_questions_per_quiz(request, pk):
    questions_per_quiz = Question.objects.filter(quiz_id=pk)
    context = {'all_questions': questions_per_quiz, 'pk': pk}
    return render(request, 'quiz/quiz_questions.html', context)
```

**Models.py**

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ForeignKey


class QuizIdentifier(models.Model):
    creator_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.creator_name


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    op1 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    op2 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    op3 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    op4 = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    quiz = ForeignKey(QuizIdentifier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null='True')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']


class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question', 'op1', 'op2', 'op3', 'op4', 'answer']
        widgets = {
            'question': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the question!'}),
            'op1': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the first option!'}),
            'op2': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the second option!'}),
            'op3': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the third option!'}),
            'op4': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the fourth option!'}),
            'answer': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter the answer!'}),
            'quiz': Select(),
        }


class QuizIdentifierForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizIdentifier
        fields = ['creator_name']
        widgets = {
            'creator_name': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your name!'})
        }
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from quiz import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeTemplateView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('add-question/<quiz_id>', views.QuestionCreateView.as_view(), name="add-question"),
    path('quiz/<str:pk>', views.get_questions_per_quiz, name='quiz'),
    path('create-a-quiz/', views.QuizCreateView.as_view(), name="create-a-quiz"),
    path('quiz-details/<str:pk>', views.QuizDetailView.as_view(), name='quiz-details'),

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# QUESTION
class QuestionCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quiz/add_question.html'
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        question_quiz_id = self.kwargs['quiz_id']
        return reverse_lazy('add-question', kwargs={'quiz_id': question_quiz_id})
```

I did this and it worked, ty for the help! After ive put the get_success_url now everytime i press submit i will get to enter a new question infinitely until i stop.

```
def get_success_url(self):
        question_quiz_id = self.kwargs['quiz_id']
        return reverse_lazy('add-question', kwargs={'quiz_id': question_quiz_id})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's Some Very Simple `Models.py`

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    creator_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField("Question", blank=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    answers = models.ManyToManyField("Answer", blank=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.TextField()
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

There are 2 Solutions :-

1.
Are you Familiar with Javascript?
Add a Button which on click add new form of five inputs for 1 question and four answers.
*Javascript*

```
// add new question and answer form
addQuestion = () => {
    var container = document.querySelector("#QuestionsContainer");
    container.appendChild("yourNewFormHere");
}
```

2. 

In the very start, ask creator how many questions he want to be in his Quiz,
And then use for loop in template file and provide that number of forms.

Comment: But why would i use many to many if is one quiz with more questions ? Isn't it just one to many?

Comment: I don't think you're Familiar with manytomantfield. if you work in VS Code, i can join you there (mytwitter = https://twitter.com/___DeshBhakt___?t=2nlPBlGZfr_zaGbvdYeSIQ&s=09).. however i gave you 2 solutions to add new question, try those out.

Comment: but i found the answer already , its the one below yours , it was simpler than what u provided and it did the job with OneToMany relationship. Thank you for your help!